# Mod_rewrite rule to remove index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to have

`site.com/index.php?s=super-smash-bros-baww-SUzohN`

redirected to

`site.com/super-smash-bros-baww-SUzohN`.

How can I do that?

Note that the number of words can be different e.g: `/index.php?s=aaa-bbb-ccc` needs to go to `/aaa-bbb-ccc`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following to the `.htaccess` file in the root directory of your site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

#redirect to remove index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\?s=([^\ &]+) [NC]  
RewriteRule ^ %1? [L,R=301] 

#process the SEF Url with index.php
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z]+)$ index.php?s=$1 [L]
```