# Remove index.php? with mod_rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

There are plenty of answers on removing `index.php` with mod_rewrite in `.htaccess` but I need to remove `index.php?` from incoming URLs and rewrite them all, i.e. `/index.php?pagename.php` to `/pagename.php` .

Either of these work separately, and they remove `index.php`

1)

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php?/(.*)$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

2)

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

But not the `?`, as the URLs look like this: `example.com/?pagename.php`

The issue is that the `?` is a special character in regex, so if that's added, I understand that it needs to be escaped. But neither of these work:

1)

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php\??/(.*)$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

2)

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php\? [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php\?/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

How do I correctly escape the `?` in `index.php?` ?

This answer does not work for me; it leaves the `?`: [Mod_rewrite rule to remove index.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9176140/mod-rewrite-rule-to-remove-index-php)

And beyond that: are there appreciable differences between the two rewrite rules?

Comment: Why not example.com/?page=pagename.php then use the page variable??

Comment: `index.php?pagename.php` are existing links; I can't change them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index\.php)?\?([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Nice! Works great. And these are 301 redirects as I see from `R=301` ?

Comment: Of course, another issue :)  It appears that most of the site is indexed by Google as /?PageName.php while also accessible and internally linked as /index.php?PageName.php . Your rule still works, but I tried `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+\?(\S+) [NC]` as a second rule below your rule to remove the `?`, but my rule appears to redirect all to index.php. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks, I see what you did, but each still redirects to root. Does the second line `RewriteRule . /%1? [R=301,L]` also need to account for the `?` by itself ?

Comment: I am trying example.com/?PageName.php  Each attempt redirects to root but still shows the `?PageName.php` in the browser bar.

Comment: It should be working. Both example.com/index.php?PageName.php and example.com/?PageName.php need to go to example.com/PageName.php

Comment: Nice! Works great. Thanks! I'll edit my question to include the `?` case.